# Vote to close box - move the close button

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

This is a minor irritation, but the close (for dismissing the dialog without taking further action, not closing the question) button on the 'Vote to close question' box is on the left.  In fact, I think all the close buttons are on the left.

Traditionally, in Windows, the close button is on the upper right.  Due to the widespread use of Windows, this has become something of a convention, bucked only by (to my knowledge) Apple's desktop OS.

Having the close button on the left seems like a violation of one of the UI design rules: [Don't Make Me Think](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/dont-make-me-think-second-edition.html).

Could we shift it to the upper-right corner, or was it placed where it was deliberately?  If so, what was the reasoning?

Edit: To be clear, I mean the 'close this dialog box' button - the big 'X' in the upper-left corner, no the buttons that allow you to cast a vote.  I mean the way to dismiss the box without casting a vote, or after you have cast one and hit the 'close' link again.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If someone who works on primarily Apple software, they would think the close on the right to be a violation of intuitive UI design.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: True.  I'd be willing to bet, however, that better than 90% of our visitors (here and on SE as a whole) are primarily Windows users.

Comment: I highly doubt that, lol. I would say that it's more of about 50/50. Or 49/49/2, the 2 being Linux users. Also, it would have to be redone for mobile platforms, and then it really would go against intuitive UI.

Comment: Just hit escape...

Comment: @jcolebrand You could hit alt+F4, too.

Comment: ehwut? I don't think ..

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Yet this stuff is made on Windows and those boxes only appear in case of administrative features... Anyway mimicking windows on a webpage is a brain-damaged idea in the first place

Answer (score 3):

I absolutely agree with you Jeff. The default location of most lightboxes is the right. Of [these](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/), only one has the close button on the left, and it is designed to look exactly like OSX. All the others have it at the top or bottom right, or not at all.

And yes, Jedi powers DO come with the diamond. It happens to be a [lightsaber crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal).

Answer (score 1):

Meh. Even if it was important to be consistent with the most-used desktop OS — which I'm not convinced of: the dialog close button doesn't get much use — changing it is a bad idea. [The web still remembers](http://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+window+buttons) when [Ubuntu did it](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/config-desktop/C/window-button-order.html).

Comment: But I don't want the question to go away, I want the dialog to go away - I may not have been clear in my question.

Comment: @Jeff You sure weren't. I'm still unconvinced, but for different reasons.

Comment: Well *I* knew what I meant.  Come on, didn't your diamond come with mind reading powers?